# IOS upgrade - pair of WS-C6509-E

Tags: cisco, switch, router, cisco-ios-12

I've got a pair of WS-C6509-Es, and it's time to upgrade their IOS.

They have been up for 5 years, so I have some concerns if they will boot up after reboot - I would like to ask your opinion if any known bugs, or something I need to have my mind on before I reload them?

Both members are identical and running `s72033-adventerprisek9-mz.122-33.SXI2a.bin`.

```
Mod Ports Card Type                                      Model             
--- ----- -----------------------------------------------------------                      
  1   16  CEF720 16 port 10GE                           WS-X6716-10GE     
  2    4  CEF720 4 port 10-Gigabit Ethernet             WS-X6704-10GE     
  3   48  CEF720 48 port 10/100/1000mb Ethernet         WS-X6748-GE-TX    
  5    2  Supervisor Engine 720 (Active)                WS-SUP720-3B      
  6   48  CEF720 48 port 1000mb SFP                     WS-X6748-SFP      
  7   48  CEF720 48 port 1000mb SFP                     WS-X6748-SFP      
  9   48  CEF720 48 port 1000mb SFP                     WS-X6748-SFP      

   Hw        Fw                Sw           
------ ------------ ------------ -------
  1.0   12.2(18r)S1       12.2(33)SXI2 
  2.2   12.2(14r)S5       12.2(33)SXI2 
  2.3   12.2(14r)S5       12.2(33)SXI2 
  4.5   8.1(3)            12.2(33)SXI2 
  2.3   12.2(18r)S1       12.2(33)SXI2 
  1.5   12.2(14r)S5       12.2(33)SXI2 
  1.5 and 12.2(14r)S5     12.2(33)SXI2  --> other member has Hw 1.10 

Mod  Sub-Module                  Model                        Hw     
---- --------------------------- ------------------ ----------- ------- 
  1  Distributed Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-DFC3C         1.3   
  2  Centralized Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-CFC           2.0   
  3  Centralized Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-CFC           2.0   
  5  Policy Feature Card 3             WS-F6K-PFC3B           2.2   
  5  MSFC3 Daughterboard               WS-SUP720              2.4   
  6  Centralized Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-CFC           4.1   
  7  Centralized Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-CFC           2.0   
  9  Centralized Forwarding Card       WS-F6700-CFC           2.0
```

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. You can paste the text and use the Preformatted text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Removed the off-topic question for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, there are issues with line cards that were manufacture between a certain date period that will fail to boot once they have been on for a certain period of time already and are rebooted/reseated.

[This](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/637/fn63743.html) is the field notice for the line cards that fail after a power cycle. If you contact TAC a head of time they can check by serial number if you are likely to be affected or not (that way you can have spears on standby).

In additional to that, if this is a VSS pair you need to ensure that the IOS image is on both SUPs and that the config register and boot variable are in sync. Sometimes this doesn’t all happen automatically and when you reboot the old SUP is still on the old IOS and complains.

Use the command `show bootvar` to check that the boot variable is the same on both SUPs. If it isn’t or if the config register isn’t the same a handy trick is to set the config reg to 0x2142 for example (which is the “skip config at boot up” value), save the config, the set the config reg to 0x2102 (which is the “normal” value) and then save the config again. Hopefully this will force a sync between SUPs (you can also check with `remote command switch show boot`.

Answer (score 3):

There's bug with some line cards on this platform which leads to card crash when reboot occurs after long uptime. If this happens, the card is subject to RMA. Cisco can determine potentially risky cards by serial number. Best solution for you is to contact technical support and ask them.

You should use specific version of software based on features you're using. Again, best advisor for you is Cisco. They can verify all potential bugs and recommend good variant for your needs.